# Kendo Grid filter for the field with client template

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using jQuery, I am trying achieve the client side filter for the field/column named "Milestone/Tasks", this column contains ***client template*** with list of items for display.

How to achieve the filter for such scenario?
Any help is much appreciated.

Attached the screenshot for the reference.[image]

[image]

Comment: how is the value being presented to the client template, is it a list? concatenated string? object/Class? how do you want to be able to filter it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply David. I am generating an UnOrdered List and then presenting it to the client template..

Comment: So I have done something similar but it did involve doing the filtering on the serverside, you could pick multiple `tags` as it were and then this would be sent to the server with a fresh data request. If that works for you I might be able to dig up some code which did this operation using the MVC Helpers as a guide for you